# What is the subgroup of $O_2$ generated by two reflections in $\Bbb R^2$ about two lines of angle $\frac{2\pi}{n}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Question from a Math Exam:**

What is the subgroup of $O_2$ generated by two reflections in $\Bbb R^2$ about two lines of angle $\frac{2\pi}{n}$?

I am unable to understand the meaning of this question?
Can someone please tell me what does it mean to find the subgroup containing two lines and two reflections?

What object is being reflected?

If someone get help me to understand what to do in the problem? I will be  grateful if someone helps me out.

Comment: $O_2$ is the group of motions in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is eigher a reflection along a line that passes throught the origin or rotations. Composition of two reflections along lines with angle $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$ gives a rotation by angle $\frac{\pi}{n}$ I think. So then the subgroup must be isomorphic to some dihedral group because you've got rotations and reflections.

Comment: @mathnoob: it is actually $4\pi/n$ not $\pi/n$, and you need to divide it into two cases according to parity of $n$.